# What does `Set<Class<? extends Class<?>>> typeSet = resolverUtil.getClasses();` means?

Tags: java, types, mybatis

I'm reading one line of source code of myBatis:

```
Set<Class<? extends Class<?>>> typeSet = resolverUtil.getClasses();
```

I don't understand what's `Class<? extends Class<?>>`?

How can a type `?` extends `Class<?>`? So it extends itself?

Comment: Does the code you saw really have `extends Class<?>`? That looks like a recipe for something useless.

Comment: @Raining see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). This is useless for the function output results.

Comment: @Raining see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

`? extends Class<?>` means any class the extends class [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). However, this is redundant since `java.lang.Class` is declared `final` and therefore cannot be extended (at least in current and past versions of Java).
so the declaration can be safely simplified to

```
Set<Class<Class<?>>> typeSet = resolverUtil.getClasses();
```

**EDIT**

The signature of the method from myBatis class `ResolverUtil` is as follows:

`public Set<Class<? extends T>> getClasses()`

yes, `ResolverUtil` is parameterized itself. it accepts one generic parameter `T` that is a class that may have sub classes.  `getClasses()` will return the types (`Class` objects) of some or all of type hierarchy of `T`. the line from the question will be the result of the following declaration:

```
ResolverUtil<class<?>> resolverUtil = new ResolverUtil<>;
```

Comment: Even `Set<Class<Class>>` is pretty much useless, all you can add to the set is `java.lang.Class.class`

Comment: so you mean the set will always include at most only one item?

Comment: The only type it allows is `Class<Class>`; there's only one of those. In other words, you can't call `typeSet.add(String.class)`...

Comment: @ernest_k It may be necessary as a member of a type that specialises a type for specifically `Class`, although I tend to prefer the cockup theory.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline well... It just happens that `Class` is `final`, so that scenario is severely challenged. One possible corner where it may make sense is an environment with multiple isolated class loaders (possibility of many `Class` objects for the same class/type) but this must be very, vary rare.

Comment: @ernest_k Consider `interface Base<T> { Set<Class<? extends T>> getClasses(); ... blah blah blah.. } interface Derived extends Base<Class<?>> { ??? getClasses(); }`. Correct return type for `Derived.getClasses`? (Even with multiple class loaders, it'll always be the same `Class` object for the same type - even if the name was the same but loader different, then both `Class` and type would be different.